# Realizar un componente de Vue2 en admin lte

Tags: laravel

Instalé `admin lte` utilizando `composer` para `laravel 5.4`, debido a que esta plantilla viene con `Vue` instalado.

Sin embargo al momento de realizar un componente me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
<div id="app">
    @{{ message }}
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.27/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Si pudieras mostrar que error te arroja, seria de gran ayuda

Comment: Hola José, edita tu pregunta para incluir un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Me parece que esta pregunta ya la habian formulado y fue cerrada por lo mismo que te dicen ahora.